# Android - correct (stack based, correct back and forth) animations between activities

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition

Consider I have following hierarchy:

- level 1 activity (e.g. Main Menu)

  - level 2 activity (e.g. Calendar)

    - level 3 activity (e.g. Calendar Day)

Following use cases exist:

1. Going into the deep
2. Going back
3. Bring current activity back to the screen (after screen turned off or from the running background activities after the application was left)

Following transition behaviour is desired:

Use case 1 + 3: 
I want the old activity to slide out to the left and the new activity to slide in from the right

use case 2:
I want the old activity to slide out to the rightand the new activity to slide in from the left

I tried so many ways to achieve that with `overridePendingTransition` but no combination worked correctly... I got stuck with something like the following:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        adjustWindowAnimation(this, false);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        adjustWindowAnimation(this, true);
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void adjustWindowAnimation(Activity parent, boolean start)
    {
        if (start)
            parent.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right_in, R.anim.slide_to_left_out);
        else
            parent.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_left_in, R.anim.slide_to_right_out);
    }

//     @Override
//     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
//     {
//         adjustWindowAnimation(this, true);
//         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//     }

//     @Override
//     protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
//     {
//         adjustWindowAnimation(this, true);
//         super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
//     }

//     @Override
//     protected void onStart()
//     {
//         super.onStart();
//         adjustWindowAnimation(this, true);
//     }

//     @Override
//     protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
//     {
//         adjustWindowAnimation(this, true);
//         super.onNewIntent(intent);
//     }

//     @Override
//     protected void onStop()
//     {
//         adjustWindowAnimation(this, false);
//         super.onStop();
//     }

//    @Override
//    public void finish()
//    {
//        adjustWindowAnimation(this, false);
//        super.finish();
//    }

//    @Override
//    protected void onDestroy()
//    {
//        Crouton.clearCroutonsForActivity(this);
//        super.onDestroy();
//    }

//     @Override
//     public void onBackPressed()
//     {
//         adjustWindowAnimation(this, false);
//         super.onBackPressed();
//     }

}
```

Animations (these should work correctly):

SlideFromLeftIn:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

SlideFromRightIn:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

SlideToLeftOut:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

SlideToRightOut:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve such behaviour you need to know the reason of pause and resume. Like if its another activity is going to be presented then app plays one animation in `onPause()` but if its not (so its any other reason) then you play another animation. Same in `onResume()` - if it was some activity started and now its finished and that's why `onResume()` triggered then you play one corresponding animation but if `onResume(`) is not triggered by finishing activity (returning to app after a phone call for instance) then you play another animation.
 I'd done something similair in the following way:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity{
...
    protected boolean isGoingToAlarmActivity;
    protected boolean isGoingToSettingsActivity;
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // for animation choose
        if (isGoingToAlarmActivity){
            isGoingToAlarmActivity = false;
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
        else if (isGoingToSettingsActivity){
            isGoingToSettingsActivity = false;
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        }

        super.onPause();
    }

public void onAlarmButtonClick (View button){
    isGoingToAlarmActivity = true;
    startActivity(new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class));
}

public void onSettingsButtonClick (View button){
    isGoingToSettingsActivity = true;
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
}

...
}
```

There are only 3 activities in the project Menu, Alarm and Settings. So It goes to settings with animation "from right to left" and reversed on returning to Menu and AlrmActivity is vice versa. In AlarmActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // for animation choose
    if (isFinishing())
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

    super.onPause();
}
```

and in SettingsActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // for animation choose
    if (isFinishing())
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    super.onPause();
}
```

note: isFinishing() method of Activity indicates that activity is finishing like when user taps Back button (there are could be other reasons but in most cases it is so).